# Quiero modificar el valor de mis rows de forma que no se agreguen mas sino que se actualicen las que ya estan

Tags: c#, datatables

Actualmente tengo este output:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se podrán dar cuenta en la salida de arriba tengo tres registros pero esos registros deberían ocupar una sola fila "row" ya que se deben sumar cada vez que exista la palabra clave "TyM", pero lo único que se hace es ir añadiendo nuevas filas.

Código Actual:

```
 public bool InsertEstimador(DataTable dtEstimador)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Folio", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ClaseCoste", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Perfil", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("SemanaEstimada", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("SemanaNatural", typeof(float));
            dt.Columns.Add("Horas", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Monto", typeof(float));
            dt.Columns.Add("FechaInicio", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("FechaFin", typeof(DateTime));


            foreach (DataRow elemento in dtEstimador.Rows)
            {
                switch (elemento[1].ToString())
                {
                    case "TyM":
                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                        float resultado = dr["Monto"].ToString().Equals("") ? 0 : float.Parse(dr["Monto"].ToString());
                        dr["Monto"] = float.Parse(elemento[6].ToString())+resultado; 
                        dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0); 
                        break;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Hola @David, tal y como dice la documentacion de [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection.insertat?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataRowCollection_InsertAt_System_Data_DataRow_System_Int32_) el metodo `InsertAt()`, inserta una nueva `row` no actualiza la que quieres

Comment: @VictorManuel sabes de que forma se puede actualizar esa row o como puedo hacer sumatorias de filas de acuerdo a ciertas palabras claves.

Comment: Utiliza el AsEnumerable del DataTable para poder utilizar Linq, asi podrás obtener una colección que ya tenga los valores sumados.
[DataTableExtensions AsEnumerable](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable)

Comment: Creo que el elemento que usas es un `DataGridView` por lo que lo puedes modificar usando este codigo `dataGridView1.Rows[X].Cells["tuColumna"].Value = tuValor;`

Comment: Y si lo que quieres es modificar los valores del `DataTable` te recomiendo que leas esta pregunta de [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629644/how-to-edit-a-row-in-the-datatable) ingles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Como te he comentado la funcion `InsertAt()` no actualiza el
   valor , sino te crea una nueva row
2. Si lo que quieres es actualizar el campo directamente te sugiero que crees una variable con la suma total y luego modifiques el valor de tu celda:

   `dataGridView1.Rows[X].Cells["tuColumna"].Value = tuValor`
3. Si lo que quieres modificar el `dataTable` te sugiero que te pases por esta pregunta de [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629644/how-to-edit-a-row-in-the-datatable) en ingles donde encontraras varias formas de implementarlo